# Can i use model function when i do django orm query?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, orm

I have a model like:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ... some fields
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    def get_range_between(self, lon, lat):
        return great_circle(self.longitude, self.latitude, lon, lat)
```

And i like call this get_range_betwen func when i do this query:

```
User.objects.annotate(range=model_in_query.get_range_func(lon, lat))
```

something like this.
How i can realize this in my code and is it evan real?

Comment: What does the great_circle function do? It's looks like a spatial query, have you looked into GeoDjango? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/

Comment: What issue do you get with your current code ?